# NPM Install Same Package / Different source as devDependency

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to get NPM to install a dependency from its repository or a custom repo depending on if its meant to install production dependencies only, i.e. --production. and install as a symlink when installing dev dependencies?   I want developers to be able to run and debug from local source while production pulls from the github repo. I'm also afraid if the package.json only indicates the repo as a source, a developer will change the package.json to debug and forget to change it back when committing.

I have my package.json like this but with this it will only install the package when I allow dev dependencies and installs nothing when I don't

```
"dependencies": {
        "myPackage": "github:mygithub/mypackage",
},
"devDependencies": {
        "myPackage": "file:./../mypackage"
}
```